# Reset countdown animation c# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, timer, countdown

this is my code for an animated countdown. When bandera_countdown == false, the timer should stop and reset. It resets, but it keeps working on the background because even after reseting, the countdownStoryboard.Completed += CountdownTimer_Completed fires.

```
private void StartCountdown(FrameworkElement target)
    {
        var countdownAnimation = new StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
        var countdownStoryboard = new Storyboard();
        if (bandera_countdown == true)
        {
            for (var i = 10; i > 0; i--)
            {
                var keyTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10 - i);
                var frame = new DiscreteStringKeyFrame(i.ToString(), KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(keyTime));
                countdownAnimation.KeyFrames.Add(frame);
            }
            countdownAnimation.KeyFrames.Add(new DiscreteStringKeyFrame(" ", KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(11))));
            Storyboard.SetTargetName(countdownAnimation, target.Name);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(countdownAnimation, new PropertyPath(TextBlock.TextProperty));

            countdownStoryboard.Children.Add(countdownAnimation);
            countdownStoryboard.Completed += CountdownTimer_Completed;

            countdownStoryboard.Begin(this);

        }
        else
        {
            countdownStoryboard.Stop();
            countdownStoryboard.Remove();

        }

    }
```

What can i do to make my timer stop and begin in 10 seconds again?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is bandera_countdown ever set to false anywhere?

Maybe have an if statement inside the for loop, so if i == 1, (if if you want if i == 0) then set bandera_countdown to false.

You could also try changing the conditions on the line which starts the for loop, so where it says i > 0, you could try to change it to i >= 0, so it should run even when i == 0.

I think i understand what you want it to do, i mean from the for loop, im assuming keyTime is meant to go from 0 to 10 but it doesn't seem to be going back to 10? That may be due to the thing i mentioned before with the i > 0, as i think the for loop's last iteration will be when i == 1.

I hope this helps and if not good luck with it... and don't worry, you should definitely get another response soon enough, the people on here are normally very helpful ... :)

Just another thought i've had, you could declare the keyTime varaible outside of the for loop and give it the initial value of 10 and basically do the same thing that occurs in the for loop, that is decrease it's value by i each time and then maybe have an if statement in the for loop when i == 0, reset the value of keyTime to 10, set bandera_countdown to false and anything else you may want to do there...

Comment: Thanks!! bandera_countdown is set to false. the problem is, when that happens the timer resets to 10, but keeps running. For example, when the countdown finishes(equals 0) it fires an event handler, so lets say my countdown is in 3 seconds when bandera_countdown is set to false, so the countdowns resets and shows 10 seconds and starts counting down again, but after 3 seconds the handler fires. I don't know if im explainig myself.